# &nbsp; doesn't show in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

`&nbsp;` shows some symbol istead of space in IE? 
could you tell me why?
thanks

Comment: Tell us which symbol and what's your page encoding?

Comment: Edited your Q to make the `&nbsp;` notation actually visibile.  Anyway, it does show a space for me, so I can't answer your Q!-)

Comment: I'd say it's due to encoding issues. Try changing it.

Comment: Encoding issues with HTML entities are impossible. They were invented to avoid exactly this kind of problems. The actual problem lies somewhere else; the interpretation of the problem is just wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching your content type to "Unicode (UTF-8)" (if it is not already).

You don't see the problem in Firefox because it does a better job of autodetecting the character encoding of the HTML it parses and tries to display.

Comment: @superUntitled i've set <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />